# git submodules: track corresponding branch in submodule?

Tags: git

Say you've got a project broken out into a superproject and a submodule. Both of them have stable (master) branches and dev branches. Is there a way to set up your submodules so that the superproject tracks the submodule's dev branch from its dev branch and the submodule's stable branch from its stable branch?

What I'm imagining is something like this in `.gitmodules`:

`[submodule "subproject"]
      path = subproject
      url = http://www.github.com/nfirvine/subproject
      branch = $current_branch_name`

(I'm looking specifically at the [Ansible project](https://github.com/ansible/ansible), where their `stable-1.9` branch tracks the `devel` branch of their submodules. This seems like asking for trouble.)

You could use git attributes to specify that `.gitmodules` doesn't get merged automatically, but I'm wondering if there's something smarter than that.

Answer (score 0):

Each commit in the superproject will be associated with a specific commit in the submodule.  Submodules don't automatically update or follow branches: each time you want to synchronize, you'll need to cd to the submodule directory, checkout the branch of your choice, run `git pull`, and then commit the result to the superproject.  It's up to you to have each branch in the superproject pointing to a commit that in turn points to an appropriate submodule commit; git won't do that for you.  And when you merge branches, you'll need to sort that part out manually.

That's all assuming you don't write some awesome scripts to tame the madness, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your main project track the commit of the submodule, but you have to commit any changes.

For instance, You have a main project and a submodule, both have a master and develop branch. If you commit your submodule dir in your main project the next time you or another repo runs `git fetch && git submodule update` you will have the latest commit for the submodule.

You have to update your submodule then commit the changes, the tracking is not automated as you can have this without submodules by just updating both git repos and pulling them.